# How to compiling a QT5 project in windows, disabled the SSE2 to support AMD CPU

Tags: qt, sse2

when doing an application release, it is found the application generated by QT5.3 cannot run on AMD CPU, which does not support SSE2.
Is it possible use QT5.3 to generate an application but disabled the SSE2, in windows QT?
Many thanks.

Comment: It would have to be an extremely ancient AMD CPU not to have SSE2 support (much more than 10 years old) ?

Comment: Yes, the CPU is AMD Geode.

Comment: Wow - you have to support a 1999 CPU - that must be quite a challenge on the tools and libraries front.

Comment: [I'm afraid this will require a full rebuild from source](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTUxMDM). It so happens that Qt 5.3 specifically is the first version that uses SSE2 unconditionally by default; This means the binary builds are of no use to you. To get a working binary you will need to rebuild Qt 5.3 from scratch, configuring it with `-no-sse2 -no-sse -no-mmx` (I don't know just how crippled Geode is).

Comment: Unfortunately, `-no-sse` and `-no-mmx` results in `Unknown command line option '-no-mmx' ('-no-sse')`